# AzureAD authentication only works on local

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Ive set up my AzureAD in the portal, and an appservice that uses the AD to authenticate following instructions from microsoft.

Ive made a .net core app that uses this authorisation. It works on my localhost. But when i publish it i get this error

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: '614f66a9-xxxx-483a-8bc7-xxxxxxx'

What should i change and how come it works in my local but not when published?

This is current configuration of app:

```
 {
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "lmyName.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "******-ebd5-40d8-829b-*********",
    "ClientId": "*****-8eef-483a-8bc7-********",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

When i followed the online intructions i was directed to configure the appservice in the portal to use reply URL: /.auth/login/aad/callback

Could that be the same as callbackPath?

Comment: Have you configured the reply URLs for the app in Azure AD? It needs to contain all possible callback URLs for all your environments (or use a different app entirely in Azure AD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you can change your **reply URL** in AAD Application to be `<YourApplicaitonURL>/signin-oidc`.

**NOTE** The base address in the Sign-on URL and Logout URL settings is `http://localhost:port`.

This localhost address allows the sample app to run insecurely from your local system. Port is the default port for the Kestrel server. Update the reply URL in your AAD Application if you configure the app for production use(If you publish your App to Azure Web App service).

For example,  `https://yourapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc` or `https://www.contoso.com/signout-oidc`

You can also refer to [this Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore) to Integrate Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app.

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: Im not sure i understand. When you say "these URLs" do you mean in the app config or in azure reply urls? 

Right now the azure portal has reply url "https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc". Is this not correct?

Comment: @Lautaro  Correct! it should be reply URL in your AAD Application. it should be same as the redirecturi in your applicaiton.

Comment: Yang
Maybe i am missunderstanding or we are using different words for the same thing. If you look in my apps config there is no redirecturi. Did you mean the callbackPath?

Comment: @Lautaro, I didn't missunderstand it. You can just use `https://yourappname.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`in AAD App reply url. For .NET core App, you can see the redirecturi code logic at `AccountController.cs`

Comment: If you do localhost test, the redirect uri should just be `http://localhost:port`. If you publish your app to azure, the redirect uri would be `theURLofyourapp/signin-oidc`

Comment: I was the one missunderstanding. Ok so now i understand clearly. 
So my callbackPath in the app configuration is set to "/signin-oidc" and in my Azure portal i have reply URK "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc"

Still i get the AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application error.

Comment: I have problems only with the published app in azure. Not with my local dev version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169424/discussion-between-wayne-yang-msft-and-lautaro).