# AzureAd authentication always uses local ip address of server as redirect_url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm currently having a issue with AzureAd authentification on a remote server when using the public URL like https://mysoftware.mydomain.net.

I've added AzureAd authentication with the following lines:

```
services.AddMicrosoftWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd")
            .AddMicrosoftWebAppCallsWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { GraphApiScopes.ScopeUserRead })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

As long as I'm running the software with URL https://localhost:5001 then authentification works well, and the callback is https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc

If I am now accessing the software using https://mysoftware.mydomain.net the redirect to https://login.microsoft.com works well, but the callback will then to https://local-ip-of-my-server/signin-oidc.
To be honest I absolutely don't understand why its sending the local ipaddress of the server as redirect_uri query param to the authentification service from Microsoft.

Of course I will now get a error message from Azure telling, that the reply URL doens't match the configured reply URL as my configuration is made for https://mysoftware.mydomain.net/siginin-oidc and https://localhost:5001/singin-oidc.
If I'm now adding https://local-ip-of-my-server/singin-oidc  as redirect url in the App registration the redirect back to this IP works well but of course on the calling computer the local ip of my server is not accessible.

Hopefully it was understandable and someone is able to help me with that problem.

Greetings,

Luca

Comment: The error is just caused by the reply uri doesn't match the redirect uri in your application. see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923017/azuread-authentication-only-works-on-local?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
To be hoenst, I am not sure, if that solves my problem, because the reply URL in the App Registration is set to the correct one "https://mysoftware.mydomain.com/signin-oidc" that's what I would except to be the URL used as redircet_url. But for some reason .net automatically fills the redirect_url sent to login.microsoft.com with the local-ip of the server so it's https://ip-of-server/signin-oidc. Which of course is wrong.

Comment: Can you add complete url as reply url - add `https://` at the start?

Comment: No, sadly it's not allowed to add a full URL as callback path.
I use the appsettings.json file to set the CallbackPath: "/singin-oidc" if I add the full domain there, it sends an error message saying that the callback path needs to start with "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved...

It had nothing todo with .NET-Core.. The firewall didn't include the original header when forwarding the request to my server.

The option was called "pass-through host header".

Greetings,
Luca

Comment: Hey can you give some more details. I am facing the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is old, but it pointed me in the right direction. For myself, I had an NGINX server acting as a reverse proxy to my IIS server. What I had to do was add the following to my `server` section:

```
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```