# Active Directory redirect_uri shows IP instead of DNS name. How to provide absolute CallbackPath in code while authenticating with Azure AD?

Tags: c#, azure, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

appSettings.json:

```
 "CallbackPath": "/platform/signin-oidc",
```

This is what I get after deployment:
[image]

I think it is showing the Kubernetes IP where code is deployed. The application uses Azure front door to route requests (in case that helps). How do I fix this? Can I pass DNS name? Full callback path instead of relative path?

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018571/azuread-authentication-always-uses-local-ip-address-of-server-as-redirect-url)

But unfortunately there aren't enough details in the answer posted by the OP.

**startup.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("intercepted");
                };
            });

            var azureAd = new AzureAd();
            Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(azureAd);
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
                {
                    o.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azureAd.TenantId}";
                    options.ClientId = azureAd.ClientId;
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                    options.ClientSecret = azureAd.ClientSecret;
                    options.CallbackPath = azureAd.CallbackPath;  // POINT OF INTEREST                

                });
             
        }
```

Comment: There are two things: the redirect uri must be configured in the app registration (AAD) and you need to adjust you're callback path with the front door url: `options.CallbackPath = $"<front door domain>/{azureAd.CallbackPath}";`

Comment: @Thomas Like I have mentioned in my post, it does not allow you to provide full path. It will throw an error that the path must start with '/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the redirect uri before redirecting to the IdP like that:

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>                
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "full redirect url with front door domain";
    return Task.FromResult(0);
};
```

Comment: It still gives me url mismatch error. Even though now the redirect url in matches the one in active directory.

Comment: Could you paste the error message please?

Comment: AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '86cda223-2296-46c3-ae42-f10bacca6475'.
https://imgur.com/a/v9BtTHJ

Comment: ` context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5001/platform/signin-oidc";`

Comment: and you do have this redirect_uri `localhost:5001/platform/signin-oidc` configured in AAD for this app `86cda223-2296-46c3-ae42-f10bacca6475` ?

Comment: this should be: `context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5001/platform/signin-oidc"` rather than `context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "localhost:5001/platform/signin-oidc";`

Comment: `context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5001/platform/signin-oidc";` same error.

Comment: Normally just copy/paste what you have from Azure AD and it should work.

Comment: Yes. I was silly to have missed an 'r'. I guess that issue is resolved. I will mark your answer. Though I am still stuck because there is a infinite redirect loop for some reason

Comment: Feel free to ask another question, do you have some authorization attribute ?